# How to group an array of objects in JavaScript on specific fields using Lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

**EDIT:**
I believe this is a different problem than a simple `_.groupBy` because I am trying to group by all keys and returning an hashmap not an array.

---

I have an array of the following objects:

```
items = [
  { created_at: "01/01/2016", name: "bob", age: 21, height: 60 },
  { created_at: "01/02/2016", age: 22, height: 70 },
  { created_at: "01/03/2016", name: "alice", age: 23 }
]
```

And I am trying to transform it into this format:

```
{
  "name": [
    {
      "value": "bob",
      "created_at": "01/01/2016"
    },
    {
      "value": "alice",
      "created_at": "01/03/2016"
    }
  ],
  "age": [
    {
      "value": 21,
      "created_at": "01/01/2016"
    },
    {
      "value": 22,
      "created_at": "01/02/2016"
    },
    {
      "value": 23,
      "created_at": "01/03/2016"
    }
  ],
  "height": [
    {
      "value": 60,
      "created_at": "01/01/2016"
    },
    {
      "value": 70,
      "created_at": "01/02/2016"
    }
  ]
}
```

My requirement is I am ignoring the `created_at` field, but grouping everything else.

One solution is:

```js
var items = [
  { created_at: "01/01/2016", name: "bob", age: 21, height: 60 },
  { created_at: "01/02/2016", age: 22, height: 70 },
  { created_at: "01/03/2016", name: "alice", age: 23 }
]

var store = {}
for(var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
  var item = items[i]
  
  for(key in item) {
    if(key === "created_at") {
      continue
    }
    
    value = item[key]

    if(!store[key]) {
      store[key] = []
    }

    store[key].push({
      value: value,
      created_at: item.created_at
    })
  }
}

$('pre').text(JSON.stringify(store, null, 2))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body><pre></pre></body>
```

I was wondering if there was some cool way to do it in `lodash` ... maybe using `.map()` or `.groupBy()` or something? I don't quite get how to use them properly and am trying to learn new, more elegant ways to write the code.

Comment: It is a different problem because the other ones only group by one field and generates an array. I am grouping by keys and generating an object.

Comment: the way you have it seems pretty simple. `_.groupBy` might add unnecessary complexity. Don't use what you don't need.

Comment: yeah, since I don't use many of of lodash additional methods that often, i wasn't sure if there was a "one-liner" type method that would produce the same results as mine

Answer (score 0):

Using `reduce` might be the shortest way.

```
var baseKey = 'created_at';

var result = items.reduce(function(col, item) {
  Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key) {
    if (key === baseKey || !item[key]) return;
    var o = { value: item[key] };
    o[baseKey] = item[baseKey];
    (col[key] = col[key] || []).push(o);
  });
  return col;
}, {});
```

**JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/pLcv1am2/6/**

Answer (score 0):

You asked specifically about lodash, and so this answer is constructed using lodash.

Note I'm using the [_.chain](https://lodash.com/docs#chain) method - this makes it convenient to chain multiple operations rather than running them each separately.

One way (I'm sure there are *many* others) that gets it pretty close (not perfect) is this:

```
items = _.chain(items)
  .map(function(n) {
    var created = _.get(n, 'created_at');
    var arr = [];
    _.each(n, function(n, k) {
      if (k != 'created_at') {
        arr.push({
          'field': k,
          'value': n,
          'created_at': created
        });
      }
    });
    return arr;
  })
  .flatten()
  .groupBy('field')
  .value();
```

Which results in a collection that looks like this:

```
{ "name": 
    [ 
        { "field": "name", "value": "bob", "created_at": "01/01/2016" }, 
        { "field": "name", "value": "alice", "created_at": "01/03/2016" } 
    ], 
  "age": [
     ....
```

[Here's a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5tp3ofpk/) for playing around with this code.